# Wordpress issues with loading the website on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, firefox

as mentioned in the Title, when I load my Website on Firefox there seem to be rendering problems. Although when I load it on Chrome or Safari it looks and renders as it should. 
I will post some screenshots to make the issue even clearer.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

[Website view on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UTWk.png)

[Website view on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LYMU.jpg)

Comment: Looks like your css has some error. Validate your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error on below line, correct it.

```
src: url(â€˜library/fonts/destroy_-webfont.eot');
```

Correction:

```
src: url('library/fonts/destroy_-webfont.eot');
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the line? I'm searching for it through the source inspector in Firefox but cannot find it.

Comment: Check this line in your style.css, you will find it

Comment: Ok I found it. Perfect it works now. Many thanks! Just a little character destroyed the whole design.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you are missing some css. Check to see if the css files are being loaded properly in the developer console. If they are being loaded correctly, then you may need to add some mozilla specific styles.

Are there any other errors in the browser console that would prevent execution of the css?

Welcome to the world of cross browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So I can't see any error on the developer console in Firefox. Really annoying the fact that each browser uses his own settings and parameters!

Comment: @Fabrizio_P check the network tab and look at the resources that are loaded any in red failed to load